# How to position object on the middle of the screen in any size?

Tags: css-position

This is my entire code (sorry for h1 not being in english but it doesnt matter since all pharagraphs are dummy text too.) http://jsfiddle.net/sBKYH/

My positioning

```
.vizitka{
position:relative;
top:50%;
margin: 232px 0 0 438px;
}
```

So my problem is I was working on this webpage on my laptop and it was all perfect. But when i opened the website on my PC (with bigger screen) my cards moved to the left. How can i keep my cards on the middle so they wont be effected by screen size? And also when i changed the size of browser window, instead of staying on middle the cards when slowly up. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
.vizitka{  
  margin:232px auto 0;
  ...
}
```